# images not viewing in foodlist stored in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

trying to upload images in this recycleradapter ,images are stored in firebase database but not able to view in UI or recycler adapter food category in this below is the screenshot.

Instead of image the URL is displayed:
[image: instead of image the URL is displayed]

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageReference;


    TextView txtFullName;
    MaterialEditText edtName;
    Button btnSelect,btnUpload;
    Category newCategory;
    Uri saveUri;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 123;
    DrawerLayout drawer;


    RecyclerView recyler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("MenuManagement");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //init firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category = database.getReference("Category");
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });


         drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //set Name for user
        View headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName = (TextView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtFullName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);

        //load menu
        recyler_menu = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclermenu);
        recyler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadMenu();

    }

    private void showDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Add new Category");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please fill full information");

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View add_menu_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_menu_layout, null);
        edtName = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        btnSelect = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
        btnUpload = add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImage();
            }
        });
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadImage();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setView(add_menu_layout);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                if(newCategory !=null)
                {
                    category.push().setValue(newCategory);
                   Snackbar.make(drawer,"New Category"+ newCategory.getName()+"was added",
                           Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }

            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        if(saveUri!=null) {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
            mDialog.show();

            String imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            final StorageReference imageFolder = storageReference.child("images/" + imageName);
            imageFolder.putFile(saveUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                    newCategory = new Category(edtName.getText().toString(), uri.toString());

                                }
                            });
                        }


                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this,""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mDialog.setMessage("Uploaded"+progress+"%");
                        }
                    });

        }
}


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data  != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            saveUri = data.getData();
            btnSelect.setText("Image Selected !");
        }
    }

    private void chooseImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    private void loadMenu() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>()
                        .setQuery(category, Category.class).build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);

                return new MenuViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {

                //do binding stuff
                holder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
                holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

                        //Intent foodList = new Intent(Home.this,FoodList.class);
                        //foodList.putExtra("CategoryId",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        //startActivity(foodList);
                    }
                });
            }

        };
        recyler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
        //start listening
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

this is home.java code where the fooditems list is displayed

**Manifest file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sharma.digimenuserver">
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat error**

```
 Process: com.example.sharma.digimenuserver, PID: 29800
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:297)
        at com.example.sharma.digimenuserver.Home$9.onBindViewHolder(Home.java:252)
        at com.example.sharma.digimenuserver.Home$9.onBindViewHolder(Home.java:235)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:122)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some problems with the url. Either the url related to image is wrong or the field might contains something else. Do like this:-

```
if (! model.getImage().contains("https")) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultImg);
}
else {
    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be basically two links for every Firebase Storage file

1. Storage location
2. Download URL

[File location in Firebase Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xykAP.png)

I think you need to provide the download links of images from Firebase Storage to Firebase Database.